# If $f\geq 0$ Integrable and $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = 0$ then $f \equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove or disprove:

> Let $f\geq 0$ an Integrable function in the interval $[a, b]$. If
>   $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt = 0$ then for all $x \in [a, b]$: $f(x)=0$.

I know that if we replace Integrable with continuous then the theorem still holds. but I can't be sure about this theorem.

Comment: Hint: canging the value of a function in one point does nor change the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the function $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b)$ and $f(b)=1$. This function is integrable such that the integral vanishes but is not the zero function.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the Monotone Convergence Theorem for Lebesgue integrals.
This states that if $f_1$, $f_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions,
 $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x$ and $n$, and
$\int f_n\to L$, a (finite) limit, then $F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$
is defined (and finite) almost everywhere in $\Bbb R$ (that is except in a set of Lebesgue measure zero) and that $F$ is Lebesgue integrable and
$\int F=L$.

In this case take $f_n(x)=nf(x)$. Then $\int f_n=0$ for all $n$ and so
the conditions of the Monotone Convergence Theorem are fulfilled. Therefore
$\lim_{n\to\infty}nf(x)$ exists and is finite, almost everywhere.
That is, $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.